# Android : Hint-text color not changing even after manually setting in XML and/or Java

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I am working on an Android project in which I have an UI form, for which I am trying to change the `hint-color`.

I changed the color in base-theme, that change took effect in another project I am working on, but didn't solve the problem in this one. Then I also tried to set it in Java directly, but no change whatsoever. What am I missing or what is over-writing those values. Kindly let me know.

XML :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/register_travel_transparent_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="22dp">

    <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.RobotoTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_button_selector"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Register User"
        android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_700"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:typeface="robotoThin" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.MaterialDesignIconsTextView
            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="@string/material_icon_account"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.FloatLabeledEditText
            android:id="@+id/emailAddressTextField"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/emailAddress"
            android:textColorHint="@color/cpb_red"
            app:fletFloatingHint="@string/emailAddress"
            app:fletHintTextColor="@color/cpb_red"
            app:fletSingleLine="true"
            app:fletTextBackground="@drawable/edit_text_background_accent"
            app:fletTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_700"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.MaterialDesignIconsTextView
            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="@string/material_icon_account"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.FloatLabeledEditText
            android:id="@+id/firstNameTextField"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/firstName"
            app:fletFloatingHint="@string/firstName"
            app:fletHintTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            app:fletSingleLine="true"
            app:fletTextBackground="@drawable/edit_text_background_accent"
            app:fletTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_700"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.MaterialDesignIconsTextView
            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="@string/material_icon_password"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.FloatLabeledEditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordTextField"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            app:fletFloatingHint="@string/password"
            app:fletHintTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            app:fletSingleLine="true"
            app:fletTextBackground="@drawable/edit_text_background_accent"
            app:fletTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_700"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.MaterialDesignIconsTextView
            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="@string/material_icon_password"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.FloatLabeledEditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordAgainTextField"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/repeatPassword"
            app:fletFloatingHint="@string/repeatPassword"
            app:fletHintTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            app:fletSingleLine="true"
            app:fletTextBackground="@drawable/edit_text_background_accent"
            app:fletTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_700"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.MaterialDesignIconsTextView
            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="@string/material_icon_password"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.FloatLabeledEditText
            android:id="@+id/userCity"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="City"
            app:fletFloatingHint="City"
            app:fletHintTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            app:fletSingleLine="true"
            app:fletTextBackground="@drawable/edit_text_background_accent"
            app:fletTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_700"/>
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.MaterialDesignIconsTextView
            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="@string/material_icon_password"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.FloatLabeledEditText
            android:id="@+id/userCountry"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Country"
            app:fletFloatingHint="Country"
            app:fletHintTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            app:fletSingleLine="true"
            app:fletTextBackground="@drawable/edit_text_background_accent"
            app:fletTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_700"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.MaterialDesignIconsTextView
            style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="@string/material_icon_password"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.FloatLabeledEditText
            android:id="@+id/ageOfUser"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Age"
            app:fletFloatingHint="Age"
            app:fletHintTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
            app:fletSingleLine="true"
            app:fletTextBackground="@drawable/edit_text_background_accent"
            app:fletTextColor="@color/main_color_grey_700"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/maleRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="6.54"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="Male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/femaleRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="Female" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <mycompany.gradlecheck.Templates.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/registerUser"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle.RaisedEmpty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent_button_selector"
            android:minWidth="96dp"
            android:text="@string/register"
            android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_700"
            app:typeface="robotoMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I pasted the complete XML, just to be sure. THe hint-color right now is some sort of off-white color.

I changed this in styles.xml, which didnt help:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/primary_dark_material_dark</item>
</style>
```

Then finally I set it like this :

```
    userEmailField.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Above is just one of the variables. Same for all the fields. But still it is not getting set. What am I doing wrong? Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the color drawable itself. So try this:

```
userEmailField.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark_material_dark));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't change anything. I also cleaned the project before running it after making the changes.

Comment: How does your FloatLabeledEditText look like?

Comment: I changed it directly in FloatLabeledEditText using your code, that worked. Its  a library actually.